# Change default template in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to change the default templates in SQL Server Management Studio? For example, when I right-click on a table and I choose "Script Table as" from the context menu, I can choose select, insert, update, etc. I would like to change the format of some of these sql scripts like you can with the templates in the template explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Tis possible only in Tools -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Scripting

Comment: I was hoping for a way to modify the format in other ways such as indentation.

Comment: I think it is not possible to change something else.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit late (only five years or so), but in case anyone else stumbles upon this question:

You can go to `View -> Template Explorer` (`Ctrl + Alt + T` in SQL Server 2012) and edit the text of all the various templates that SQL uses (including for new Stored Procedures). This is much easier than tracking them down in their Windows directory. You can also add your own templates there, including giving them template parameters to be filled in later (such as `<Procedure_Name, sysname, ProcedureName>`).

You could use the above to edit the default template when clicking New -> Stored Procedure, but sadly it doesn't look as if you can reassign which template is the default (at least, I've been unable to find a way).

Answer (score 2):

For more control than tools -> options, apparently there are bunch of templates that you can change in the application directory (i.e. : `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\sqlworkbenchprojectitems\Sql`), however I couldn't find the ones for basic DML (INSERT, UPDATE etc).

Maybe just the ones for creating new objects are available.

Comment: These templates are exactly the kind of thing I want to have access to. However, these are the templates used by the template explorer and don't include the basic SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, etc. templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do DROP and CREATE statements in the same script, or otherwise generate scripts for SQL Server 2005 that are more compatible with SQL Server 2000 scripts, you mey want to check out the Scriptio tool:

http://www.codeplex.com/scriptio/