# Customize Templates beyond Grid

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

How can I add custom sql commands to the default templates(used for when you right click a table and then use `Script Table as...` then click one of those options)?

[image]

Instead of:

```
UPDATE DB.dbo.table SET col1 = 'test'
```

I would like to have:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE DB.dbo.table SET col1 = 'test'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Or any custom code really.

I did look at the [Change default template in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681645/change-default-template-in-sql-server-management-studio) question, but it didn't allow for custom sql. It allowed you to set predefined properties.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a snippet 
from redgate has a sql server intellisense (sqlprompt)
in the snippet you will hav to declare that when you press 'ur' and  tab you'll get :

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE 
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

when you have the snippet you'll be able to customize whatever you want

Comment: Can you share a link to the specific redgate product so that I can test this out?

Comment: I was able to get this to work, but it doesn't exactly solve the problem. If I use sql-prompt then I lose the ability to populate the db.tablename automatically. At this point, I don't gain much by losing the table part and gaining the transaction part.